# How do I prove that if $|c|<1$, then ${n^{2/5}c^n}$ converges to 0?

Tags: real-analysis

I've been stuck on this problem for over an hour now. I'm wanting to prove this using the comparison lemma, but I'm not sure how to set it up with what I need. Here's what I have and where I'm getting stuck:

Let ${b_n}={n^{2/5}c^n}$ and $b=0$. Then ${b_n}$ converges to $0$ if there's a non-negative number $C$ and an index $N_1$ such that for a sequence ${a_n}$ which converges to $a$, $|n^{2/5}c^n| \leq C|a_n-a|$. Let ${a_n}={(n+1)/n}$ which converges to $a=1$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Now I want to say that for all indices $n\geq N_1$ that $|n^{2/5}c^n|\leq (n+1)/n$, but I'm getting stuck trying to generalize this for any $c$ where $|c| < 1$. Is the comparison lemma even a smart direction to head for this problem? I feel like there's something I've learned about proving a sequence is convergent based on convergent subsequences, but I'm not finding it in my notes. Really what's giving me trouble, I think, is the alternating positive-negative sequence you get if $-1<c<0$ because I don't know how to handle it; I'd normally look at if it's monotonic and bounded, but its absolute value is monotonic, not it itself..

Comment: If the absolute value is monotonic and converges to $0$ what do you think is going to happen with the sequence without absolute value?

Comment: @rlartiga That'd mean if ${b_n}$ is negative, then $0 < {b_{n+1}} < -{b_n}$, and if ${b_n}$ is positive, then $-{b_n} < {b_{n+1}} < 0$, I think.

Comment: What I mean is:
$$-|b_n|\leq b_n \leq |b_n|$$

Comment: If you're having trouble for $|c|<1$, then I believe you can use the ratio test for the series to show convergence.

Answer (score 3):

Since $|c|< 1$ it follows that $|c| = 1/(1+b)$ where $b>0$.

Hence, using the Bernoulli inequality

$$0<|n^{2/5}c^n|=\frac{n^{2/5}}{(1+b)^n}<\frac{2n^{2/5}}{n(n-1)b^2},$$

and convergence to $0$ follows from the squeeze theorm.

Answer (score 1):

If $c=0$, then $b_n \to 0$ trivially.

Consider the sequence $n|c|^n, \ 0 <|c|<1$.

For $n> \dfrac{|c|}{1-|c|}$ we have $$n(1-|c|) > |c| \Leftrightarrow n > (n+1)|c| \Leftrightarrow n|c|^n > (n+1)|c|^{n+1}$$ ie, $n|c|^n$ is a bounded and decreasing sequence, hence it converges to $L$.

With algebra of limits we get $(n+1)|c|^{n+1} \to |c|L$, and then we have $L=0$.

This finish the job, because $$-n|c|^n< n^{\alpha}c^n < n|c|^n, \  \forall \ \alpha \le 1$$ and apply squeeze theorem.